# Soap UI ORACLE SQL parameter not working

Tags: sql, oracle, groovy, soapui

Hi This is the code we wrote

def workerNo = context.expand( '${WorkerNo#WorkerNo}' )
log.info("workerNo : " +workerNo)

sql.eachRow("Select distinct A.NO as workerNumber, A.ACTV_IN as activeIndicator, A.ty as workerTypeCode, NVL(trim(A.JOB_CD),' ') as jobClassCode, A.FMLY_NM as lastName, A.GIV_NM as firstName, A.LOGIN_ID as login, substr(A.MID_NM,1,1) as middleName, .... from WE F where ....And   H.Fk_Region_Cd = I.Region_Cd(+) and ***A.NO =***  ***:workerNo***  ")

Its not working am not sure why. Instead - A.NO = 'xxx' is working.

Am trying to read a value frmo datasource WorkerNo property name is WorkerNo.

Pass it to SQL as above for Oracle DB.

Thanks

Comment: Please consider fixing up your code markup to make it more legible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *incorrectly* mixing Groovy and SoapUI syntax!

`:workerNo` is the SoapUI syntax that you could use in a JDBC step. What you have here is a Groovy step, so you need to use Groovy syntax: `A.NO = ${workerNo}`.

Comment: Yup Thanks !! Lemme try it